# MongoDB count of records that are published before 30 days

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection named `JobPosting` and it has a field named `publishDate`, what i want to do is to get count of records that are published before last 30 days.
What i have tried is:

```
db.JobPosting.aggregate([
    {$match:{
      "publishDate":{$gt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000*60*60*24*30)}
    }}, 
    {$project:{
      "publishDate":{$gt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000*60*60*24*30)
    }}, 
    {$group:{
      _id:publishDate, 
      "count":{$sum:1}
    }}
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do just this, no need for `aggregation` usage;

```
db.JobPosting.find( { publishDate: { $lt : new Date(ISODate() - (1000*60*60*24*30) ) } } )
             .count()
```

Get the count of documents in `JobPosting` where the `publishDate` field is before today - 30days. Since you want the dates *before* (today - 30days) point,
 you have to use `$lt`. [Tested on MongoDB web shell.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/insert-documents/)